# SQLite with android error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am relatively new to programming and android,and i am working on a little notepad app.   I learned how to use SQLite from a tutorial on the web,but something is wrong..when i am running the app,it keeps telling me that there are no columns in the name...  but there are!    what am i doing wrong?  i checked the syntax a dozens of times,and i did it like the tutorial did one by one.      I know this question was here before more than one time,but when reading the answers, i still couldnt find a solution to my specific problem.  basically i just added 2 notes with title and text and wanted to present them in the main activity in a ListView,but nothing is showing up because of the database problem.
Help is very very appreciated :)    thx in advance

this is the classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notesDb";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
    private static final String NOTE_ID = "_id";
    private static final String NOTE_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String NOTE_TEXT = "text";
    private static final String NOTE_CREATION_DATE = "creationDate";

    public DatabaseManager(Context context){

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_NOTES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"(" + NOTE_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ NOTE_TITLE + "TEXT,"
                + NOTE_TEXT + "TEXT," + NOTE_CREATION_DATE + "TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTES_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addNote(Note note){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NOTE_TITLE, note.getTitle());
        values.put(NOTE_TEXT, note.getText());
        values.put(NOTE_CREATION_DATE, note.getCurrentTime());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

    public void deleteNote(Note note){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, NOTE_ID + "?=",new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())} );
        db.close();
    }

    public String[] listNotes(){
        ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[]notesArray = new String[0];
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery,null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                tempArray.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_TITLE)));
            }
            while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        notesArray = tempArray.toArray(notesArray);
        return notesArray;
    }



}
```

the note object:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Note {

    private int id;
    private String text;
    private String title;
    private String creationTime;
    private String currentTime;


    public Note(){


    }


    public String getCurrentTime(){
        return getDayOfMonth()+"/"+getMonth()+"/"+getYear()+" "+getDay()+", "+getHour()+":"+getMinutes();
    }

    public String getMonth(){
        int currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
        String month = new String();
        switch(currentMonth){
        case 0:
            month = "01";
            break;
        case 1:
            month = "02";
            break;
        case 3:
            month = "04";
            break;
        case 4:
            month = "05";
            break;
        case 5:
            month = "06";
            break;
        case 6:
            month = "07";
            break;
        case 7:
            month = "08";
            break;
        case 8:
            month = "09";
            break;
        case 9:
            month = "10";
            break;
        case 10:
            month = "11";
            break;
        case 11:
            month = "12";
            break;
        }
        return month;
    }

    public String getDayOfMonth(){
        int currentDayOfMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String dayOfMonth = new String();
        if(currentDayOfMonth<10){
            dayOfMonth = "0"+currentDayOfMonth;
        }
        else{
            dayOfMonth = ""+currentDayOfMonth;
        }
        return dayOfMonth;
    }

    public String getYear(){
        String year = ""+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return year;
    }

    public String getDay(){
        int currentDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String day = new String();
        switch(currentDay){
        case 1:
            day = "Sun";
            break;
        case 2:
            day = "Mon";
            break;
        case 3:
            day = "Tue";
            break;
        case 4:
            day = "Wed";
            break;
        case 5:
            day = "Thu";
            break;
        case 6:
            day = "Fri";
            break;
        case 7:
            day = "Sat";
            break;

        }
        return day;
    }

    public String getHour(){
        int currentHour =  Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        String hour = new String();
        if(currentHour<10){
            hour = "0"+currentHour;
        }
        else{
            hour = ""+currentHour;
        }
        return hour;
    }

    public String getMinutes(){
        int currentMinutes = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        String minutes = new String();
        if(currentMinutes<10){
            minutes = "0"+currentMinutes;
        }
        else{
            minutes = ""+currentMinutes;
        }
        return minutes;
    }


    public void setText(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return this.text;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

the main activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(this);
        Note n1 = new Note();
        Note n2 = new Note();
        n1.setTitle("n1 title");
        n1.setText("n1 text");
        n2.setTitle("n2 title");
        n2.setText("n2 text");
        db.addNote(n1);
        db.addNote(n2);
        String[]notes = db.listNotes();
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,notes);
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.notes_list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

}

and the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/board"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/note"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/notes_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Comment: -1 for not quoting the exact message and identifying the specific line where it is raised.

Comment: `NOTE_CREATION_DATE + "TEXT"` will concatenate as `creationDateTEXT`.

Comment: (Hint: Print your assembled strings.)

Comment: the exact massage is:  "table notes has no colums named creationDate.

Comment: I don't understand..what do you mean by print my strings?

Comment: `System.out.println(CREATE_NOTES_TABLE);` -- You'll find that the string does not look like you (presumably) intended.

Comment: (And you still haven't identified the line where the error occurs.)

Comment: (The reason there no column named "creationDate" is that you named it "creationDateTEXT".)

Comment: so what is the proper way to write it?

Comment: the line of the error in the Logcat is number 1 .  this is the first error from the logcat

Comment: ah...are you telling me that i supposed to put space inside the "TEXT,"  ..like this:  " TEXT,"  ?

Comment: ok..worked!  thank you,a silly mistake of mine.  well i am a noob so excuse me :))

Comment: (If you study the log carefully you will see that the specific line number in your code where the exception was raised was identified.  It's a *lot* easier to debug a problem if you know where the error is coming from.)

Answer (score 0):

A semi colon inside the query is missing for your table creation string CREATE_NOTES_TABLE string. Include a semicolon (;) inside the string just after the final ")";  ie. Make it ");";

Comment: no..that's not it.  tried to do what you said but still not showing :(

Comment: It asking me to insert the those values (creationDate,text and title)  into the table.  but i did that already.  something wrong with the way i do it maybe?   i did it just like the tutorial teached

Comment: solved the problem, thank you all for your help.  a silly syntax mistake..i forgot to put a space in the string.